# How to check a checkbox inside our canvas Power Apps?

Tags: powerapp, powerapps-canvas

I have a checkbox named Checkbox2 and I want to check it, I tried this formula:`(UpdateContext({Checkbox2.Value:true}) & Checkbox2.Value=true)` inside the App's OnStart but none of them worked.

I also tried:

```
If(CountRows(Filter(colAmountRadioOption, Value =  varRecord.Amount.Value))=0,UpdateContext({Checkbox2.Value:true});Set(varmanualAmount,varRecord.Amount.Value),false);
```

and

```
If(CountRows(Filter(colReasonRadioOption, Value =  varRecord.Reason.Value))=0,Checkbox2.Value=true;Set(varmanualReason,varRecord.Reason.Value),false);
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You must assign true or false value to a variable in the **OnStart** and use that variable in '**Default**' property of the checkbox content (It is not possible directly assign a value to PowerApps component).

[image]